# Converting multidimensional object array to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, angularjs

I have an array of object which i want to convert to a `JSON` string but i recieve the following error: `JavaScript exception :Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

From what i understand this is because there is a loop in references. i've searched here on SO for solutions and someone came up with a 'replace function'. this looked something like this:

```
var cache = [];
    JSON.stringify(o, function(key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
            if (cache.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                // Circular reference found, discard key
                return;
            }
            // Store value in our collection
            cache.push(value);
        }
        return value;
    });
    cache = null; // Enable garbage collection
```

but using this gives me the following error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

i think this solution doesn't really fits my needs, because i am not intrested in all the elements ofthe array that i'm trying to convert. These elements are added are 3rd party(google maps) so i have no influence on their child objects.

This is a screenshot of my array object:

[image]

i am only interested in the following items:

```
Tour
  -id
  -name
  -days :
      -id
      -name
      -markers :
          -dayId
          -title
          -position :
              -nb
              -ob
      -thumbs :
         - 0
         - 1
         - ...
```

because the object array is created by several functions/services/factories is it difficult to make a fiddle or provide some code samples.

Any sugestion how to convert an array like this to JSON is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, i ended up making my own array with just the elements that i needed:

```
function CreateJson(tour){
    var sJson = {};

    sJson.name = tour.name;
    sJson.id = tour.id;
    sJson.days = [];
    sJson.markers = [];
    sJson.thumbs = [];

    for(i = 0; i < tour.days.length; i++){
        sJson.days.push({
            id: tour.days[i].id,
            name: tour.days[i].name
        });
        for(j = 0; j < tour.days[i].markers.length; j++){
            sJson.markers.push({
                id: tour.days[i].markers[j].id,
                dayId: tour.days[i].markers[j].dayId,
                name: tour.days[i].markers[j].title
            });
        }
        for(k = 0; k < $scope.thumbs.length; k++){
            sJson.thumbs.push($scope.thumbs[k])
        }
    };
```